# Pass numeric value to UI in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In R shiny I need to pass a numerical output from server.r to ui.r. What is the best way of doing this? I tried as.numeric(textOutput('num')) which doesn't work.

I need to replicate this example

[By changing the loop condition variable, (in this case 1:5) into a variable like 1:textOutput('num')](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html)

Comment: please provide sample code and what you tried

Comment: Please refer to the link I added.

Comment: It sounds like `uiOutput` and `renderUI` are the concepts you need. Else the UI does not get computed by R while running.

Comment: This numeric value is needed for including it in a UI widget ? `renderUI` is the way to go. Otherwise, your question is not clear enough.